# How should I setup assets in Rails 3.1 to be able to show images that're created on fly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, assets

I've Rails 3.1 application which generates some images in 'public/scene/ticket_123/*.png' on fly. It works normally in development mode, but in production all assets should be precompiled. So I can't use files that I've generated after application started.
Setting  config.assets.compile = true  hasn't solve my problem. Situation is only worse since ticket number changes - so images are in different directories which are continiously created on fly too.
How should I setup assets to be able to show images that're created after an application was started?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I only found a work around by copying all my images into "`public/images`" and changed all the links to the new path.

That worked for me for the moment. I wait until somebody comes up with a better idea.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If found solution.

```
# In view I wrote
<img src=<%= mycontroller_image_get_path :filename=>file_name %> >
# In controller I created GET action
def image_get
  send_file params[:filename], :disposition => 'inline', :type => 'image/png'
end
```

But you should care that file you're trying to send is in "#{Rails.root}/public" directory otherwise send_file says it can't found the file. (May be it is not necessary in /public but in Rails.root anyway). To change this behavior it can be useful to read this topic [Can I use send_file to send a file on a drive other than the Rails.root drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789120/can-i-use-send-file-to-send-a-file-on-a-drive-other-than-the-rails-root-drive)